# Excel Function - Convert unicode to ascii

Tags: excel, unicode, excel-formula

Is there any function in Excel (2010) which decode unicode to ascii text?

One column in my sheet contains word/sentences in Portuguese.

For Example:

```
Esse Jean Ã© feio nÃ©
```

Should become

```
Esse Jean é feio né
```

`Ã©` - This letter in the text is not Portuguese, is there any function to convert this to Portuguese font format i.e `é`.

How do I decode above text to original format `Esse Jean é feio né` in excel?

Comment: Note that Unicode isn't an encoding (not a binary one, anyway), and that ASCII can't encode all Unicode characters. It's a bit unclear what it is you want to do, but it looks like your data has been misinterpreted in terms of encoding.

Comment: I have edited and question for better understanding

Comment: It's still a bit unclear what the terms ‘Unicode’ and ‘ASCII’ are doing in your question. Do you know that the original data was encoded in a Unicode-based encoding? And `Esse Jean é feio né` can't be encoded in ASCII, since `é` does not exist within its set of characters.

Comment: Forgot about the unicode, I have that text in excel file and i need to convert the this symbol to Ã©  to é...

Comment: Is there any easy way to do this, there are some symbols across the text , i want to convert that into character

Comment: Something has gotten garbled and UTF-8 has been converted to ASCII (`Ã©` is 0xC3A9 which is `é` in UTF-8) There will be no built in way to simply fix this, Search & Replace?

Comment: I have done search and relplace since it is a letter in some words. Its not getting fixed

Comment: May I just say....OUCH. Why oh why would Excel NOT simply import what it surely must be capable of DETECTING in the source file? `<goofy>Yuck, yuck. Hey therrr I see a buncha é characters in this import yuck yuck...better turn them inta garbage for ya yuck yuck!</goofy>` fkn Microsoft

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sound an awful lot like you failed to import the data correctly.

If you still have the original data, I suggest you import it again and use **65001: Unicode (UTF-8)**.

If you do not have the original data, you can still trick Excel into importing your data again. I suggest you copy the incorrect column to it's own Excel file, then go to **File** and **Export** the new file to **Text (Tab delimited)**. Next import (found under **Data** -> **From Text**), set the file type to **Delimited** and the File origin to **65001: Unicode (UTF-8)**.

You should now have a new Excel file with fixed encoding. Copy the column from the new file and paste it in the old file.

Comment: Thank you all !! For your wonderful help... i can understand things now